# How to display image with user input URL?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

Having a bit of trouble getting started on making a simple HTTP image browser. I am doing this in C# and using a Windows Form Application. The requirements included are that I prompt the user for a URL of an image which is inputted in a textbox (I believe I have to use an HTTPwebRequest, but not sure), and then click a button and display the image in a picturebox. I'm used to writing console applications, and am brand new to the Windows Forms commands, which is why I'm looking for some help.

**In addition, but not necessary, is the inclusion of a status code of the image, as well as associated headers that are returned by google's web server, which are displayed in textboxes. Sorry if this is too vague, I am just completely lost, and anything would help.

Comment: First thing to do (both to make this question less vague and to move you closer to completion) is to pull the pieces of the problem apart. You're familiar with .NET console apps? Try making one of those that, given a hard-coded URL, will retrieve an image and the response headers you care about. If you have trouble doing that, come back here and ask a precise question about downloading images from the web in .NET. Once that's done, work on the UI bits, and ask specific questions about those when you get stuck. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

If you drop a TextBox, a Button and a PictureBox onto your form, you can use the code below to download an image from the internet, convert it to an image and show it in the PictureBox.

- m_urlTextBox is the TextBox the user can use to enter the image URL.
- m_downloadButton is the button that the user clicks to initiate the download.
- m_pictureBox is the PictureBox used to draw the downloaded image.

The code for the Click event handler for the download button is shown below.

```
private void m_downloadButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (var client = new WebClient())
    {
        var imageData = client.DownloadData(m_urlTextBox.Text);

        var converter = new ImageConverter();
        var image = (Image)converter.ConvertFrom(imageData);

        m_pictureBox.Image = image;
    }
}
```

I've made no attempt to handle errors or conversion failures, but this should give you the gist of what is required. If you need to inspect the headers associated with the image, you should look into WebRequest.Create / GetResponse / GetResponseStream etc. instead of using WebClient.